# Problema no icone na barra do navegador

Tags: html

Senhores estou com problema sobre o ícone na barra de tarefa .

Estou usando o Brackets para copilar ai quando eu uso a opção "Live Preview"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

logo em seguida a janela abre mostrando que está tudo ok fucionando [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mais logo quando eu upload dos arquivos, da algum problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <title>exemplo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!----fonts google------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="js/alerta.js">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logoT3.png" >
    


    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->

    <style>
        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

    <!--------------------------------------------------------- Menu ------------------------------------------------------------>

 <body>
             <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xl-">
        <img src="img/logoT5.jpg"></div><div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 col-xl-"><h1 class="w3-xlarge  w3-animate-opacity" >exemplo</h1></div></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Verifique se o endereço da imagem está de acordo, e se estiver usando linux verifique as letras maiúsculas e minusculas do endereço todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito provavelmente o erro é por causa disso! `rel="shortcut icon"` esse `rel` não existe, e é estranho que tenha funcionado mesmo que localmente, mas no serve com certeza deve haver alguma *config* que não reconhece esse atributo e não mostra o `favicon` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Para usar da forma que usou vc tem que ter a extensão `.ico` para garantir que vai funcionar mesmo em browsers mais antigos e que o *server* vai reconhecer o `MIME Type` corretamente. A forma como vc declarou provavelmente só vai funcionar nos IE mais antigos.

Esse forma de `<link>` que vc declarou não existe no **HTML5** e não vai funcionar devido tb ao `<!DOCTYPE html>` que vc colocou. Leia mais detalhes aqui: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon

> "*... **shortcut is not a valid link relation**. Indeed, **it doesn’t show up in section 4.12.5 of the HTML5 specification** on ‘link types’ ... **rel="icon" would suffice to specify a favicon**.*"

Aqui tem um exemplo de construção de tags para o `favicon`, ele atende as especificações mais antigas e mais modernas tb.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Esse site pode te ajudar a gerar esses arquivos: https://realfavicongenerator.net/

---

Caso queira dar suporte de forma mais segura para o IE uma alternativa é tb incluir essa tag no código

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: primeiramente obrigado !segundo se remotamente ta funcionando como eu vou saber se outras funções que eu adiciono pode estar errada ! só testando pra saber ? você tem algum canal no youtube ?

Comment: @caiquesey aqui tem um validador de código online da própria W3C vc pode colocar seu código lá e ver se acusa algum erro. O Favicon costuma ficar "impregnado" no cache do navegador, e mesmo se vc deletar ou trocar por outra imagem é normal ele continuar mostrando a imagem antiga por um tempo... Eu não tenho canal no Youtube não, mas a minha dica é que leia muito! Principalmente a Documentação da Mozilla que é bem completa, e faça exercícios replicando códigos que vc viu etc. Precisando é só dar um toque []´s

Answer (score 0):

Tente `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Se não der, verifique se a localização do icone bate com da hospedagem,
pode ser que no seu PC esteja em `img/logoT3.png`, mas quando na hospedagem tenha outro diretorio.